# html template not rendering correctly for dynamic html content in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have strange issue in HTML template rendering, I have template `index.html`, in that template i passing dynamic content, here i have placed that code

```
<p class="font-secondary paragraph-lg text-dark" style="color: black;">
            {{ portal_contact_home_about|safe }}
        </p>
```

in `portal_contact_home_about` this variable it contains data like `"<p>Lorem ipsum</p>"`, so data should have to be render like this

```
<p class="font-secondary paragraph-lg text-dark" style="color: black;">
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </p>
```

but it is rendering it as wrong way

```
    <p class="font-secondary paragraph-lg text-dark" style="color: black;"></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

instead of using two p tags use as follows

```
<div class="font-secondary paragraph-lg text-dark" style="color: black;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```